# Remove trailing zeros of a double only when necessary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Im making a calculator app and I am using a double for the precision. I didn't want the extra zeros and the decimal to be displayed so I changed the place holder token to "%.f". Because I did this if I do a problem on the calculator that does involve decimals they don't show up.

My question is basically if there is any way to have the %.f be used only when its necessary. If there is no way, what do you recommend doing to make it so I only have a decimal when its actually needed. Thanks.

Comment: You can use NSDecimalNumber to do the calcs in decimal, so they behave more like pencil and paper.  And/or you can scan the formatted number and "trim" away trailing zeros (and the decimal point, if appropriate).  (Of course, you probably need to add a "small delta" first to avoid getting 123.4599998.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `NSDecimarlNumber`, but to answer your question, you can user `NSNumberFormatter` to format the output for a double.

```
double someNumber = 1.9;
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSLog(@"%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:someNumber]]);
```

My output

> 2014-01-13 11:30:41.429 DTMTestApp[23933:907] 1.9

Answer (score 2):

For a calculator consider using `NSDecimalNumber` combined with `NSNumberFormatter`. There are going to be lot's of problems using floating point. Consider: (2 / 3.000000001) * 3.000000001, the result will not necessarily be exactly 2.

Comment: (But even NSDecimalNumber cannot calculate (2/3) * 3 correctly...)

Comment: @Martin True. Actually `NSDecimalNumber` does as does `float` and `double`. (2/3)*3 is a bad example, I changed that in the answer.